# Distinction between pre-hire onboarding and post-hire onboarding

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, business-language, general-vs-specific

Wikipedia talks of onboarding as "the mechanism through which new employees acquire the necessary knowledge, skills, and behaviors to become effective organizational members and insiders." And [about.com has an article](http://management.about.com/od/people/a/Onboarding-Before-Employee-Starts.htm) that discusses "Onboarding: Before The Employee Starts".

This is too broad for my usage.

In naming projects for my HR department, how can I logically separate tasks relating to bringing the employee in the door:

- Get ID badge
- Get parking pass
- Process W-4 paperwork
- Clean out office

and post-first-day organization socialization:

- Initiate sales training
- 30-day follow up
- Introduction to our products
- Employee shadowing

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. Your title asks about *pre-hire onboarding* and *post-hire onboarding*, yet the question seems to ask about different steps in *post-hire onboarding*— and the steps you list for integrating a new employee into the organization I have only known as *orientation*.

Comment: This really isn't a question of English.  Write a memo with 2 paragraphs saying about what your question does, and make it a checklist for the new hire "onboarding".  Onboarding...good lord.  What a term for learning where the coffee and bathrooms are.

Comment: Orientation for everything prior to starting the actual job and onboarding for the subsequent training.

Answer (score 1):

Consider *induction*:

> the action or process of inducting someone to a position or
>   organization. A formal introduction to a new job or position.

> The CO said this year would see a focus on staff inductions,
>   expectations and education, as well as team activities. [source](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/induction)

Answer (score 0):

Why not **Employee Orientation Training Day 1**

and

**Employee Orientation Training Day 2**

Answer (score 0):

My work uses **pre-boarding** and **post-boarding**.  When you board you are with the company, as you would board a plane.  I am not sure what onboarding means.